# IllegalStateException: Spring Data REST controller ... must not use @RequestMapping on class level as this would cause double registration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller, spring-data

After Spring Boot Upgrade to version 2.5.6 I am not able to compile the project because of the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'restHandlerMapping' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.DelegatingHandlerMapping]:
> Factory method 'restHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception
> is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spring Data REST controller
> MyController must not use @RequestMapping on class level as this would
> cause double registration with Spring MVC!

This is my controller:

```java
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping("/api/my")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/x")
    public ResponseEntity<...> x
  
  @GetMapping("/y")
    public ResponseEntity<...> y
  
  @GetMapping("/z")
    public ResponseEntity<...> z
}
```

I was able to solve the problem by removing `@RequestMapping` annotation and moving "/api/my" to each method, but is there any way to change it on the class level?

**EDIT:**
To be precise, there is already a config class

```
@Configuration
public class RestModuleConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        config.setReturnBodyOnCreate(true);
        config.setReturnBodyOnUpdate(true);
        config.setBasePath(Constants.API_BASE_URI); // "/api"

        ...
    }
```

so in fact my controller does not contain base uri ("/api"), previously I just wanted to simplify the example as much as possible.

```java
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping("/my")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/x")
    public ResponseEntity<...> x
  
  @GetMapping("/y")
    public ResponseEntity<...> y
  
  @GetMapping("/z")
    public ResponseEntity<...> z
}
```

Does it mean that the only way is to define constant paths for each Controller? (e.g. Constants.MY_CONTROLLER_BASE_URI)

Comment: Debugging using http://localhost/actuator/mappings could help. I have similar problem, but in my case manual annotation of all methods (instead of class) does not help. It somehow ends up in 404 (not found) error during tests of given endpoint.

Comment: Made sample project to showcase problem. https://github.com/luvarqpp/poc-springRequestMapping.git See also the only commit in `updateNotWorking` branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following configuration, which is intended to be used by Spring Data REST to expose repository resources:

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api/my
```

And defining the controller as:

```java
@BasePathAwareController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/x")
    public ResponseEntity<...> x
  
    @GetMapping("/y")
    public ResponseEntity<...> y
  
    @GetMapping("/z")
    public ResponseEntity<...> z
}
```

Comment: @Peters_ have you tried this?

Comment: I think this is the same

Comment: Maybe, but have you tested it?

Comment: This is not going to help because "/my" path is specific for just one controller and there are much more Controllers which I also need to change.

Comment: But then using `@BasePathAwareController` makes no sense.

Comment: Why? All of controllers have common "/api" path

Comment: Then you can only apply `/api` as a general configuration. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api/my
```

to your application.properties equivalent thing if using yaml

Comment: Like above...
This is not going to help because "/my" path is specific for just one controller and there are much more Controllers which I also need to change.